# How to determine the range of values of t for which the sinusoid $x(t)=Ae^{-at} \cos{\omega t}$ has negative second derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing

Considering the damped sinusoid $$x(t)=Ae^{-at} \cos{\omega t}\tag{1}$$

I would like to obtain the exact ranges of t where the second derivative is negative.

$$x'(t)=-aAe^{-at}\cos{\omega t} - Ae^{-at} \omega \sin {\omega t}\tag{2}$$

Note that this first derivative is zero when $\tan{\omega t}=\frac{-a}{\omega}\implies t=\frac{tan^{-1}{\frac{-a}{\omega}}+k\pi}{\omega},k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Note also that if we consider $t$ a function of $k$ we can calculate the difference in t between two successive critical points: $t(k+1)-t(k)=\frac{\pi}{\omega}$. Because we have a sinusoid, this is the distance in t between a max and a min or vice versa.

Now I calculate when the second derivative is zero

$$x''(t)=a^2Ae^{-at}\cos{\omega t}+aAe^{-at} \omega \sin{\omega t} +aAe^{-at} \omega \sin{\omega t} - Ae^{-at} \omega^2 \cos{\omega t}\tag{3}$$
$$x''(t)=Ae^{-at}(\cos{\omega t}(a^2-\omega^2)+2a\omega\sin(\omega t))\tag{4}$$
$$x''(t)<0 \implies \cos{\omega t}(a^2-\omega^2)+2a\omega\sin(\omega t) < 0\tag{5}$$
$$-\tan{\omega t}>\frac{a^2-\omega^2}{2a\omega}\tag{6}$$
$$\tan{\omega t}<\frac{\omega^2-a^2}{2a\omega}\tag{7}$$
$$t<\frac{tan^-1\big({\frac{\omega^2-a^2}{2a\omega}}\big)}{\omega}\tag{8}$$

I am not sure how to interpret this result.

If we take a specific case where $a=0.25$ and $\omega=1$ we have $x(t)=e^{-0.25t}$, we have:
[image: Sinusoid, first derivative and second derivative]

The condition we derived for $x''(t)<0$ is $t<tan^-1{\frac{1-0.25^2}{2*0.25*1}}=1.08$.

From the graph and intuition, it seems that there is an inflection point every time the graph of $x(t)$ crosses $x=0$. From this point of view, the sign of the second derivative changes every $\frac{\pi}{\omega}$ length of t, or in our example every length $\pi$ in t. Here is a graph of
$$\tan{\omega t}<\frac{\omega^2-a^2}{2a\omega}=\frac{1-0.25^2}{2*0.25*1}$$

[image]

Clearly, $tan(\omega t)$ spends most of its time below $\frac{\omega^2-a^2}{2a\omega}$.

Considering the result obtained above, namely $$t<\frac{tan^-1\big({\frac{\omega^2-a^2}{2a\omega}}\big)}{\omega}$$

How do we get this result that the sign of second derivative is half the time positive and half the time negative? This result of t smaller than a certain value seems to imply otherwise, namely that the second derivative spends much more time being negative than positive.

Comment: When you get to $\tan{\omega t}<\frac{\omega^2-a^2}{2a\omega}$, try plotting a graph of each side of the inequality. You'll see that there are multiple ranges of $t$ for which this is true. You need to take care when taking inverse functions when there are multiple values.

Comment: By the way, dividing both sides by $\cos(\omega t)$ without changing the direction of inequality requires the assumption that $\cos(\omega t) > 0$.

Comment: The crucial step is considering the two cases as @Cem indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start at equation $(5)$ from the original question:

$$x''(t)<0 \implies \cos(\omega t)(a^2-\omega^2)+2a\omega sin(\omega t)<0$$
$$\cos(\omega t)(a^2-\omega^2)=-2a\omega sin(\omega t)$$

**Case 1)** $\cos(\omega t)>0 \implies -\frac{\pi}{2} < \omega t <\frac{\pi}{2}$

$$\infty>-\tan(\omega t)>\frac{a^2-\omega^2}{2a\omega}$$
$$-\infty <\tan(\omega t)<\frac{\omega^2-a^2}{2a\omega}$$
$$-\frac{\pi}{2 \omega}<t<\frac{\tan^{-1}{\frac{\omega^2-a^2}{2a\omega}}}{\omega}$$

**Case 2)** $\cos(\omega t)<0 \implies \frac{\pi}{2} < \omega t <\frac{3\pi}{2}$

$$-\infty<-\tan(\omega t)<\frac{a^2-\omega^2}{2a\omega}$$
$$\infty >\tan(\omega t)>\frac{\omega^2-a^2}{2a\omega}$$
$$\frac{3\pi}{2 \omega}>t>\frac{\tan^{-1}{\frac{\omega^2-a^2}{2a\omega}}}{\omega}$$

We can visualize the two cases. The green portion below is the result of Case 1): it is range of $t$ in the interval $-\frac{\pi}{2\omega} < t <\frac{\pi}{2\omega}$ in which the second derivative is negative. The purple portion is the result of Case 2): the range of $t$ in the interval $\frac{\pi}{2\omega} < t <\frac{3\pi}{2\omega}$ in which the second derivative is negative. Note also that I added the red portion, which is where the second derivative is positive.

**Indeed, the second derivative is negative half the time and positive half the time.**

[image]

Another way to visualize this:

[image]